# is it possbile in mysql to select column from table where column doesnt contain something?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

if column1 has 1 2 3
and column2 has 1.2 3 4.1

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table
WHERE column2 (doesn't contain ".");
```

is that possible ? and what is the translation of it ?

i don't want the output to show the row that has a DOT in column2

so the output would only be 2,3

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE column2 NOT LIKE '%.%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column1,column2 FROM table WHERE column2  NOT LIKE '%yourstring%';
```